# Реализация cat file | grep

Tags: g++, c++, linux

Здравствуйте! Как с помощью C++ реализовать передачу данных из потока?
К примеру, команда grep получает данные из cat: cat file | grep
Компилятор gcc, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Обычный вывод в стандартный поток вывода. Разве нет?

Comment: std::cin или getline(std::cin,...) прекрасно читают. Только не нужно забывать проверять, не закрыли ли файл (это просто значит, что программа, которая генерирует данные завершила работу).

Comment: Сначала выполняется команда cat, а потом значение, которое она вернула, передается в grep. cin ведь считывает только во время исполнения программы.

Comment: и "не во время работы программы" считывать ничего не получиться.

скорее всего grep будет запущен, сразу после cat. и будет обрабатывать построчно (может по несколько строк сразу) данные.

Comment: В том и вопрос, как такое реализовать в С++?

Comment: Может это как-то поможет http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/main.c

Comment: Причём тут C++? Это функции операционной системы. Есть в системе pipe'ы и шелл поддерживает их использование -- чудесно. Выводитет в stdout, читайте из stdin (в c++ -- cout/cin), а в команде задавайте перенаправление. Причём наличие pipe'ов не строго обязательно -- в msdos и производных от неё системах ("мастдаях") command.com эмулировал трубы через временные файлы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот простой пример, на плюсах. Задача - добавить номера строк в начале строки

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    int n = 0;
    while (!std::cin.eof()) {
        std::getline(std::cin, s);
        n++;
        std::cout << n << " " << s << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

конструкция вида `cat filename.txt | ./a.out` - работает.

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо большое!